# Extract part of string when delimiter is not fix

Tags: java, android

I am Trying to extract the words from the string but not able to do so

**My String**

```
String inpt="@[[4861:contact:An gela]] and @[[5163:contact:Bash]] and #asda @[[8888:contact:Dash Dash]]";
```

**Expected out**

```
String[] output={"@[[4861:contact:An gela]]","and","@[[5163:contact:Bash]]","and","#asda","@[[8888:contact:Dash Dash]]"}
```

I Tried with this logic(dON'T get confused with HTML tag that was part of my application )

```
String inpt="@[[4861:contact:An gela]] and @[[5163:contact:Bash]] and #asda @[[8888:contact:Dash Dash]]";
        getHtmlTag(inpt);
public void getHtmlTag(String inpt){
        String[] inptArr=inpt.split("&");
        for (int i = 0; i < inptArr.length; i++) {
            if(inptArr[i].contains("@")){
                String temp=inptArr[i].replace("[","");
                String temp1=temp.replace("]","");
                String temp2=temp1.replace("@","");
                list.add(temp2);
                String stop=getRequiredStringValue(temp2);
                finaldString=finaldString+" "+stop;
            }else {
                extraList.add(inptArr[i]);
                finaldString=finaldString+" "+inptArr[i];
            }
        }
    }

 public String getRequiredStringValue(String str){
        String userID="";
        String userName="";
        String tag="";
            String inputStr[]=str.split(":");
            for (int j = 0; j < inputStr.length; j++) {
                userID=inputStr[0];
                userName=inputStr[2];
            }
            tag="<a href='index.php?option=com_community&view=profile&userid="+userID+"'>"+userName+"</a>";
        return  tag;
    }
```

Comment: What have you tried, what do you have now?

Comment: @EugenPechanec I edited the question check what I did there and where i am Lacking

Comment: Hmm, a tokenizer, what about something like this? http://cogitolearning.co.uk/?p=525

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this with a RegEx and String split method.
In your case (based on what I understand from your Input and Expected output) :

```
String[] output = input.split("\\s+(?![^\\[]*\\])");
```

This RegeEx will split the string on the space but except those between "[ ]".